# how to use VLAN priority to filter packet

Tags: networking

Now I am using intel X520 10G nic, the driver is ixgbe
how to filter packet by VLAN priority?
i.e, I just want those packets which VLAN priority are 1.

as I known vconfig is used to tag VLAN priority Not filter by VLAN priority.

X520 support the flowdirector(perfect filter), but I can't find anything about the VLAN priority filter setting, looks its filter set are ip src/dst,port,vlan id,etc

heard thatbroadcom is able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use iptables and the `--tos` options to filter by TOS values.